# Titanium Studio / PHP - Open links in webview on iOS

Tags: php, ios, codeigniter, webview, titanium

I have a CodeIgniter system that can send messages to an app. The messages are sent as HTML and injected into a WebView in the app. However, on iOS, any links in the HTML cannot be clicked.

I've read that, for some reason, you have to manually add click event listeners to the links and call the fireEvent method with the url. If I want to do that, I'd have to modify the HTML before it is returned from the server. How can I scan through the HTML (as a string) and insert onClick attributes?

Or, is there a way to simply enable the app to open the links naturally, like Android does? At this stage it doesn't matter if they open in the WebView or Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting willHandleTouches:false on your WebView

> willHandleTouches : Boolean Explicitly specifies if this web view
>   handles touches.
>
> On the iOS platform, if this web view or any of its parent views have
>   touch listeners, the Titanium component intercepts all touch events.
>   This prevents the user from interacting with the native web view
>   components.
>
> Set this flag to false to disable the default behavior. Setting this
>   property to false allows the user to interact with the native web view
>   and still honor any touch events sent to its parents. No touch events
>   will be generated when the user interacts with the web view itself.
>
> Set this flag to true if you want to receive touch events from the web
>   view and the user does not need to interact with the web content
>   directly.
>
> This flag is true by default to retain backwards compatibility with
>   previous behavior.
>
> Default: true

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView-property-willHandleTouches

Comment: That seemed to do it. Thanks. By the way, is the backwards compatibility anything to be concerned about? We're really only aiming for iOS6/7/8 and Android "equivalents".

Comment: No, the "previous behaviour" refers to behaviour in previous Titanium SDKs, I believe not in different OS versions.